# removeif() not working on list returned by jpa

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I've some problem understanding why I can't use removeIf() on a collection returned by jpa but I can use an iterator to do so.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-pu")
private EntityManager em;
@Override
public void removeUserFromGroup(String username, Group group) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Group.getByName", Group.class);
    query.setParameter("name", group.getGroupName());
    Group qGroup = (Group) query.getSingleResult();
    // this works
    // Iterator<User> i = qGroup.getUsers().iterator();
    // while (i.hasNext()) {
    // User o = i.next();
    // if (o.getUsername().equals(username)) {
    // System.out.println("eqqq");
    // i.remove();
    // }
    // }
    System.out.println("class: " + qGroup.getUsers().getClass().getName());
    // org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList
    qGroup.getUsers().removeIf(u -> u.getUsername().equals(username));// doesn't work
}
```

Comment: That is hard to believe, since the removeIf() default implementation is basically the commented code that you posted. BTW, I don't know which doc you're looking at, but https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/indirection/IndirectList.html clearly shows that IndirectList implements List. It even extends Vector.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right it does implement list, I just woke up and idk I missed it.

Comment: @JBNizet But I'm positive the lambda expr doesn't work for me while the iterator does.

Comment: Do you have any errors? What is the actual result? I'm afraid "doesn't work" is not sufficient description here. By the way, you could try to use `TypedQuery` instead of `Query` to avoid casting when calling `query.getSingleResult()`

Comment: @Sva.Mu thanks for the tip. By doesn't work I mean that I have no error and the size of the list stays the same. I'm not sure how I could check what's happening internally ?

Comment: You could use your debugger. You could add print/log statement into your predicate.

Comment: Which EclipseLink version are you using? Try switching to latest version.

Comment: I mentioned EclipseLink, not Eclipse. I can see in your code that the list implementation is org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList, which is EclipseLink specific implementation so I am guessing your JPA provider is EclipseLink. The version you are using may not be JDK8 compatible. Alternatively I believe you could work around that by creating a new list from that IndirectList implementation and use that for the operation you need.

Comment: @PetrosSplinakis Oh sorry. Thanks for clearing that up. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The typical reason for such strange behaviour is that you have custom implementations of hashCode (and equals). If in such case you change the object and that causes the hashCode to be different, then with JDK collections it is impossible to remove the object from a Set even with iterator.remove().
The JDK collections do implement the remove by recalculating the hashCode and performing a deletion of the object with that hash. If the hash has changed the removal fails and that is ignored by JDK implementations though they return true as result of the removal what implies that the collection has actually changed even tough it did not. Sad but true.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect, another path is to throw a new list to solve the problem... ex:

```
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(getEvento().getAtividade())) {
    Set<Atividade> listAtividade = getEvento().getAtividade();
    getEvento().setAtividade(new HashSet<>());
    getEvento().getAtividade().addAll(listAtividade);
}
getEvento().getAtividade().removeIf(a -> 
a.getEspecialidade().getId().equals(especialidade.getId()));
or
getEvento().getAtividade().removeAll(getListAtividadeNotSelected());
```

Answer (score -2):

most probably the actual answer often is  neither `Equals / Hash` (please use Lombok with `@EqualsAndHashCode`) nor creating a new List (just hides the actual issue).

In fact it is rather most probably the usage of `Arrays.asList` or `Collections.singletonList` which creates a immutable `ArrayList`.

Assume you have a OneToMany/ManyToMany relation in JPA, so a Collection - lets be it a Group with members. Group / User both are proper JAP `@Entity`

```java
var user1 = new User();
var user2 = new User();
var group = new Group();


group.addMembers(Arrays.asList(user1,user2));
group = groupRepository.save(group);

// will throw an exception
group.getMembers().removeIf((user) user.getId() == 1);
```

The reason for that is, that `Arrays.asList(user1,user2)` created an actual **immutable** array with a forced fixed size. Running remove on it, will fail with `OperationNotSupport`.

Since `Arryas.asList` and `Collections.singletonList` are anyway clunky ( as you have to pick former for 1+ and latter for 1 element) and in both cases you can an immutable array you might not be aware of, rahter use Guavas

```java
Lists.newArrayList(user1,user2);
Lists.newArrayList(user1);
```

Which works for any size and the array will be mutable.

Be aware that this issue can become more hidden if you use JPA tooling since it expects a mutable list and can through you far more crypted exceptions if it fails to manipulate it.